Testcontainers + VSCode devcontainer timeout when starting a container exposing a port
Whenever I try to start a container using Testcontainers (NodeJS) using VSCode devcontainer (docker-ouside-of-docker approach) and I define a Network for the container and I expose a port, it fails with the following error:
Port 32803 not bound after 60000ms

It doesn't happen if I do not add a custom network to the container, but I need to do so.
It works just fine when executed outside the devcontainer.
This is my devcontainer.json file:
{
    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-outside-of-docker:1": {}
    },

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    "postCreateCommand": "npm ci",

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "pkief.material-icon-theme",
                "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
                "christian-kohler.path-intellisense",
                "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
                "vscode.git",
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
                "cucumberopen.cucumber-official",
                "kakumei.ts-debug",
                "alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete",
                "abhinabaghosh.cucumberquick"
            ]
        }
    },

    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    "remoteUser": "root"
}

This is my (typescript) code:
    const network = await new Network().start()

    const startPostgresContainer = async () => {
        return (
            new GenericContainer('postgres:12.13')
                .withEnvironment({ POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'xxx' })
                .withEnvironment({ POSTGRES_USER: 'xxx' })
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withNetworkAliases('db')
                .withExposedPorts(5432)
                .start()
        )
    }

    try {
        this.postgresContainer = await startPostgresContainer()
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error('Error starting container:', err)
    }

